# gulp command can not fetch file

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

Here is my gulpfile

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {

 mix.sass('app.scss',  'resources/css');

    mix.styles([
        'libs/bootstarp.min.css',
        'app.css',
        'libs/select2.min.css'
    ]);

});
```

I have a "css" folder in resources.
the following files are in that folder.
    'libs/bootstarp.min.css',
                'app.css',
                'libs/select2.min.css'

but when running "gulp" command, I receive the following error

```
- resources/assets/css/libs/bootstarp.min.css <-- Not Found
   - resources/assets/css/app.css <-- Not Found
   - resources/assets/css/libs/select2.min.css <-- Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason they are not found is because the styles function starts from the root folder, not resources/css.

Other problems I see is that you have a typo in the filename bootstrap.css (you have 'bootstrap') and your styles method is not outputting a file to anywhere where your application can publicly access it.

Try the following code. FYI, you can also chain these methods

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.sass('app.scss',  'resources/css/app.css')
       .styles([
          'resources/css/libs/bootstrap.min.css',
          'resources/css/app.css',
          'resources/css/libs/select2.min.css'
       ], 'public/css/app.css');

});
```

Comment: it gives the following error. :\

- resources/assets/css/resources/css/libs/bootstrap.min.css <-- Not Found
   - resources/assets/css/resources/css/app.css <-- Not Found
   - resources/assets/css/resources/css/libs/select2.min.css <-- Not Found

why is it entering to assest folder each time :\

Comment: had to cut paste my css and js folder to assets. now solved.